# How the head is representing the first object

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
class LinkedLIst(object):
    def __init__(self, head= None):
        self.head = head

e1 = Element(1)
ll = LinkedLIst(e1)
print(ll.head) #pointing towards e1 object
print(ll.head.value) # printing the value as 1 of e1 object
```

In this code how the head is representing the e1 value as I have not mentioned anywhere that head is first object

Comment: You should look into how the __init__() works. It is a constructor and is called when the object is first initialized.

Comment: @anosha_rehan I have the understanding of constructor that self.head  = head is executed but how the head is representing the e1 object

Comment: @bonthusaireddy when you are calling ll = LinkedLIst(e1), this calls ___init__ and e1 is passed as head and self.head = head line will assign e1 to head for ll object.

Comment: @bonthusaireddy when you make the `ll` and pass `e1` to it, you are basically sending it as the head argument of the `def __init__(self, head= None)` and therefore initializing it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment I got the answer
because I have defined a class as `class LinkedLIst(object):`
on calling  ll = LinkedLIst(e1) the e1 is passed to head through init method if no argument is there then head = None.
Thanks for the help.